# How do I combine the arrays and make my own array with ID?

Tags: php, arrays

I make a query to the database and I print this. As you can see, the `page_id => 2`  can be made into one array.

```
Array
(
    [page_id] => 3
    [name] => Add Me
    [article_category] => Celebrities
    [count_article_category] => 1
    [average_ctr] => 5.555560111999512
)
Array
(
    [page_id] => 2
    [name] => I Too Had a Love Story
    [article_category] => Celebrities
    [count_article_category] => 7
    [average_ctr] => 2.525434238570077
)
Array
(
    [page_id] => 2
    [name] => I Too Had a Love Story
    [article_category] => Desi
    [count_article_category] => 1
    [average_ctr] => 2.892319917678833
)
Array
(
    [page_id] => 2
    [name] => I Too Had a Love Story
    [article_category] => Lifestyle
    [count_article_category] => 1
    [average_ctr] => 2.3632400035858154
)
Array
(
    [page_id] => 2
    [name] => I Too Had a Love Story
    [article_category] => Sports
    [count_article_category] => 1
    [average_ctr] => 2.150439977645874
)
Array
(
    [page_id] => 1
    [name] => Indian Celebrities
    [article_category] => Celebrities
    [count_article_category] => 2
    [average_ctr] => 2.7356200218200684
)
Array
(
    [page_id] => 1
    [name] => Indian Celebrities
    [article_category] => Hilarious
    [count_article_category] => 1
    [average_ctr] => 0.7684919834136963
)
```

I want the array to look like this.

```
 [2]
    (
        [Celebrities] => 7
        [Lifestyle] => 1
        [Desi] => 1
    )
```

I tried the following code which runs in the foreach loop. I understand that my logic or my coding is wrong, but I am not able to comprehend my mistake.
Please do help.

```
if (isset($data['page_id'])) 
{
  if (array_key_exists($data['page_id'], $pages_data)) 
  {
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($pages_data);
    $pages_data[$data['page_id']] += array(
      $data['article_category'] =>  $data['count_article_category'],
    );
  } else {
    // $pages_data[$data['article_category']] = $data['average_ctr'];
    // $pages_dat a[$data['page_id']] = $data['page_id'];
    $pages_data[$data['page_id']] = array(
      $data['article_category'] =>  $data['count_article_category'],
    );
  }
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($pages_data);
}
```

Comment: Maybe with `array_combine`

Comment: Good work so far to collect your efforts and organize what you've tried and what's went wrong. Your efforts make it easier for us to help. Maybe you can also include what the result/output was when your code ran (the code at the bottom that you made to try solve the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here we go:

```
$pages_data = array();
foreach ($datas as $data) {
    if (isset($data['page_id'])) {
        // create new element for $pages_data[$data['page_id']] if it does not exists
        if (!isset($pages_data[$data['page_id']])) {
            $pages_data[$data['page_id']] = array();
        }

        // if it exists - just add certain values:
        $pages_data[$data['page_id']][$data['article_category']] = $data['count_article_category'];
    }
}
```